# How can I get Internet provider information from Wi-Fi programmatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I found `PLMN (MCC + MNC)` to use MNC(Internet Provider) as Mobile Network Info to display to user,

can be obtained by using `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()` or `TelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator().`

I couldn't find `Internet Provider` info when it comes to Wi-Fi.

Is there a way to get Internet Provider information programmatically while in Wi-Fi?